# Django Default Image is showing

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

why i can't see default image here below are my model and profile.html file:

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Profile.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% block content %}
        <div class="content-section">
            <div class="media">
            <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{user.email}}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- FORM HERE -->
        </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: are you sure you have an uploaded image for that profile? Looks like the path is ok and if the default image IS showing that could be the only case

Comment: It's not a good idea to do it like that. You should just check in the template if the user has a profile pic and if not show the default image.

Comment: i have uploaded image to media folder named default.jpg. so i should use this default image for all the users if i haven't uploaded a specific picture for them but it doesn't do that

Answer (score 0):

in templates you can check the image exists or not, if not can show a default image from static file as follows

```
 {% if user.profile.image %}
 <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
 {% else %}
 <img src="{% static 'img/default.png' %}">
 {% endif %}
```